# How to add (procedure) a new Folder to the Hierarchy using T-SQL

Tags: sql

based on the table below:

```
(
   FolderID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   ParentFolderID int NOT NULL,
   FolderName nvarchar(255) NOT NULL,
   FolderOrg hierarchyid NOT NULL,
   CreateDate date NOT NULL
   CONSTRAINT def1_CreateDate DEFAULT GETDATE(),
   Title varchar(20) NULL
) ;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need to do is add a record, wouldn't something as simple as this work?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_InsertFolder
  (@parentFolderID int, @folderName nvarchar(255), @folderOrg hierarchyid, @createDate date, @title varchar(20)) 
AS
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO table1
(ParentFolderID, FolderName, FolderOrg, CreateDate, Title)
VALUES 
(@parentFolderID, @folderName, @folderOrg, @createDate, @title);
END 
;
```

Usage:

```
EXEC usp_InsertFolder '1', '2', 0x58, '2012-10-10', 'title goes here';
```

If that's not what you need, please clarify the question.